# How to get a nested function's namespace in Python?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def make_caller(fn):
    def inner():
        fn()
    return inner

def random_function_1(): pass
def random_function_2(): return 42
def random_function_3(): return 69

callers = [
    make_caller(random_function_1),
    make_caller(random_function_2),
    make_caller(random_function_3),
]
```

Now all the functions in `callers` are called `inner`:

```
>>> [x.__name__ for x in callers]
['inner', 'inner', 'inner']
```

Using `callers`, how can I get `random_function_1`, `random_function_2`, and `random_function_3`?

Comment: Add `inner.original_function = fn` just before the `return` line so you have access to the original function.

Comment: I can't change the code. `callers` is the only thing I can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using callers, how can I get random_function_1, random_function_2, 
>   and random_function_3?

They can accessed using the **__closure__** attribute:

```
>>> [caller.__closure__[0].cell_contents for caller in callers]
[<function random_function_1 at 0x1004e0de8>, <function random_function_2 at 0x1004e0e60>, <function random_function_3 at 0x103b70de8>]
```

The *__closure__* attribute is documented in the section on callable types at [https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=**closure**#the-standard-type-hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__closure__#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat and do this:

```
>>> callers[0].func_closure[0].cell_contents.__name__
'random_function_1'
```

However, if the function is more complex (has more free variables than just `fn`), you will have to link this up with `callers[0].func_code.co_freevars`.  Also, fiddling directly with the closure objects like this is a dubious business.  Ultimately, `inner` throws away the information about the name of the function it wraps; you can only get it back via this sort of cheating.  If `make_caller` wanted others to be able to know the name of the wrapped function, it should have explicitly made that information available.